# yacc segmentation fault i dont know why

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdb, yacc

when i try to use lex and yacc to make a simple test, change c struct to java class.i have meet several questions, i think i don't understand the yacc's grammer.
here's the code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int yylex();
extern FILE* yyin;
extern FILE* yyout;
void yyerror(const char *s);
void starFileWriteTitle(FILE* file, char* structName);
void starFIleWrite1(FILE* file, char* datatype, char* identifier);
void starFileWrite2(FILE* file, char* datatype, char* identifier);
void starFIleWrite3(FILE* file, char* datatype, char* identifier);

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
%}

%union {
    char* str;
}

%token <str>IDENTIFIER 
%token <str>dataType
%token TYPEDEF STRUCT SEMICOLON LBRACE RBRACE LBRACKET RBRACKET
%type <str>structDeclaration 
%type <str>memDeclaration

%%

program:
    structDeclaration          {starFileWriteTitle(yyout, $1);}
    ;

structDeclaration:
    TYPEDEF STRUCT IDENTIFIER LBRACE memDeclaration RBRACE SEMICOLON 
    {
        printf("}\n");
        $$ = $3;
    }
    ;

memDeclaration:
    dataType IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON    
    {
        starFIleWrite1(yyout, $1, $2);
        starFIleWrite2(yyout, $1, $2);
        starFIleWrite3(yyout, $1, $2);
    }
    |dataType IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON memDeclaration
    {
        starFIleWrite1(yyout, $1, $2);
        starFIleWrite2(yyout, $1, $2);
        starFIleWrite3(yyout, $1, $2);
    }                   
    ;
%%

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}

void starFileWriteTitle(FILE* file, char* structName)
{
    char* path = "finalJavaClass.java";
    FILE* newFIle = fopen(path, "w");
    char buf[64] = "";
    fprintf(newFIle, "public class ");
    fprintf(newFIle, structName);
    fprintf(newFIle, "\n{\n");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file))
    {
        fprintf(newFIle, "%s", buf);
    }
    fclose(newFIle);
}

void starFIleWrite1(FILE* file, char* datatype, char* identifier)
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    char str[32] = "\tprivate ";
    strcat(str, datatype);
    strcat(str, " ");
    strcat(str, identifier);
    strcat(str, ";\n");
    fwrite(str, strlen(str), 1, file);
}

void starFIleWrite2(FILE* file, char* datatype, char* identifier)
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    char str[128] = "\tpublic void set";
    strcat(str, identifier);
    strcat(str, "(");
    strcat(str, datatype);
    strcat(str, " val)\n\t{\n\t\tthis.");
    strcat(str, identifier);
    strcat(str, " = val;\n\t}\n");
    fwrite(str, strlen(str), 1, file);
}

void starFIleWrite3(FILE* file, char* datatype, char* identifier)
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    char str[128] = "\tpublic ";
    strcat(str, datatype);
    strcat(str, " get");
    strcat(str, identifier);
    strcat(str, "()\n\t{\n\t\treturn ");
    strcat(str, identifier);
    strcat(str, ";\n\t}\n");
    fwrite(str, strlen(str), 1, file);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unvalid %s\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!yyin) {
        perror("fopen1");
        return 1;
    }

    yyout = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if(!yyout){
        perror("fopen2");
        return 1;
    }

    yyparse();

    remove(argv[2]);

    fclose(yyin);
    fclose(yyout);
    
    return 0;
}
```

lex file has omit, when i compile and run the code, ./output cstruct.h outputfile.java
it's shows segmentation fault.
when i use gdb to debug it, b in 82,93,106.the gdb infos as follow

```
(gdb) 
114         fwrite(str, strlen(str), 1, file);
(gdb) 
115     }
(gdb) 
yyparse () at cstruct.y:51
51          |dataType IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON memDeclaration
(gdb) 
503         yystack.s_mark -= yym;
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040374a in yyparse () at y.tab.c:503
503         yystack.s_mark -= yym;
```

i dont know how to solve this problem, please help me, thx a lot! T T

gdb and make breakpoint, found where it down, but dont know why and how to solve it.

Comment: Can you replace each sequence of `strcat`s with a single call to `snprintf`?